# Searching for AND OR

Tags: bug, chat, search

Trying to search *Stackoverflow Chat* for **AND** or **OR** results in an error:

[image: cuteness overload]

```
curl -iL --head 'http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=AND&room=11'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 145
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /error?aspxerrorpath=/search
Set-Cookie: .ASPXBrowserOverride=; expires=Mon, 25-Nov-2013 18:57:39 GMT; path=/
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 18:57:39 GMT

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 3312
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: .ASPXBrowserOverride=; expires=Mon, 25-Nov-2013 18:57:39 GMT; path=/
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 18:57:39 GMT
```

Comment: i am almost about to try something more of sql injection..

Comment: Just repro'd on Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.57 m). Trying to add other things to the search box such that the `and` or `or` are last like `obj c and` also triggers this, but `obj c and test` does not.